# Is Objectstore Not Shared Through Cluster Environment?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule4

I have an API that is called via scheduler and I want to store a variable so that the next time the scheduler kicks in it somehow recalls that variable (count) and increment it. I tried using objectstore here but I am having an issue since my API runs in a clustered environment. I think the objectstore value it not shared across the cluster environment. Tried changing the persistent value to false (so that it store the data in memory) but still does not work. Did I miss something or that is really how it behaves? If it is the later, is there any other possible solution knowing that saving the value in actual database is not feasible/available? Thank you.

Adding config for the objectstore

```
<os:object-store name="CounterStore" doc:name="Object store" doc:id="5e0b1de8-318f-49b1-ab7f-47d29f1631d2" persistent="false" config-ref="CounterStoreConfig"/>
<os:config name="CounterStoreConfig" doc:name="ObjectStore Config" doc:id="7be6b1a6-d0e0-45d4-a52a-2080a5d54802" />
```

We have our own domain for the anypoint platform and I'm seeing /cloudhub in the url in the runtime manager so I'm assuming that we are running in the CloudHub. We are using the Mule 4.

Comment: Please share the configuration of the object store. Are you using a cluster on prem? what version of Mule?

Comment: Updated the post to include the mule version and the object store configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CloudHub does not support clusters. It does support multi worker deployments, where the same application is deployed to more than one worker. That means that the cluster object store implementation is not available in CloudHub. You can use the Object Store v1 (deprecated) or the recommended v2. Both allow to share an object store between workers. You need to name the object store according to the documentation. That means that for Mule 4/object store v2 it should be called `_defaultPersistentObjectStore`. Also remove the persistent attibute

https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store/#object-store-notes:

> For CloudHub applications using Mule 4, if you choose Object Store v2,
> Object Store v2 overrides the _defaultPersistentObjectStore object
> store.
>
> For CloudHub applications using Mule 3, Object Store v2 overrides the
> _defaultUserObjectStore object store. To use Object Store v2 in Mule 3 CloudHub applications, set the Object Store reference field to the
> _defaultUserObjectStore value.

Note that Object Store implementations in CloudHub do not lock between workers so it may not be useful for you:

> Using Object Store v2 with multi-worker CloudHub applications might result in data discrepancies or key clashes.

Comment: I tried naming my object store to _defaultPersistentObjectStore buy I'm getting this error : Can't perform operation on '_defaultPersistentObjectStore'. ObjectStore not initialized. I also checked that we are running in a Multicast Cluster. Does it change anything? Based on the objectstore platform matrix support https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/The-Different-Types-of-Object-Stores-Explained, I can use it in any of the three.

Comment: If you are running a cluster you are not deploying in CloudHub. You may be confusing Runtime Manager (the management UI) with CloudHub.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed in the Runtime Manager that our Target Type is Multicast Cluster. With that, can I use the Mule Object Store instead of the OS v2?